# How do I select record with no pair?

Tags: hana, sql-scripts

[image]

Hi guys I hope you can help me, How do I pair the same record but also I want to select the record that has no pair like the 95 in the credit.

Here is my code I can actually pair the same record on Debit and Credit but also I want to show the record that has no pair.

```
select 
 A."ShortName" as "BP Code",
 A."LineMemo" as "Remarks",
 A."Debit",
 A."Credit",
 B."LineMemo" as "Remarks",
 B."Debit",
 B."Credit"
from JDT1 A
inner join
(
 select
  "ShortName",
  "LineMemo",
  "Debit",
  "Credit"
from "JDT1" where "TransType" = '18' /*A/P Invoices*/
) B on A."Debit" = B."Credit" and A."ShortName" = B."ShortName"

Where "TransType" = '46' /*Outgoing Payments*/
and A."ShortName" = 'D-0003'
and A."RefDate" between '2020-01-01' and '2020-12-31'
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: a left join b where table a has the data but b might be missing

Comment: What if the same business partner will do two transactions for the same amount in the same date? Looks like the model is incomplete. Anyway, you need `FULL JOIN` to include rows from both sides (where no debit or credit record has corresponding joined record).

Comment: Please show the result you _want_, not the result you _have_